# how to sort two table data in django

Tags: django

**models.py**

```
class Engineer(models.Model):
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=60, unique = True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s,%s'% (self.id,self.full_name)

class TestcaseCache(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    package_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    summary = models.TextField()
    pre_requisite = models.TextField(blank = True,null=True)
    author_id = models.ForeignKey(Engineer, related_name = 'author')
```

**views.py**

Here i want to sort the testcasecache data by author name but in testcasecache table there is foreign key of engineer table not name of the engineer and i want to sort testcasecache table by engineer name

```
global flag
if flag==0:                       
    testcase_object_array=TestcaseCache.objects.filter(project=pid).filter(feature=fid).order_by('-author_id')
    flag=1
else:
    flag=0                
    testcase_object_array=TestcaseCache.objects.filter(project=pid).filter(feature=fid).order_by('author_id')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use two underscore for related lookups;

```
TestcaseCache.objects.filter(project=pid).filter(feature=fid).order_by('author_id__name')
```

or

```
TestcaseCache.objects.filter(project=pid).filter(feature=fid).order_by('-author_id__name')
```

Advice: don't use `id` for foreign keys, I mean use `author` not `author_id`. filter can take all parameters;

```
TestcaseCache.objects.filter(project=pid, feature=fid).order_by('author__name')
```